# Should I place validation code in domain model or keep it external?

Tags: php, oop

I am working on some user registration code, and I'm wondering where the best place is to put my validation code.  I can create a user validation object and pass the user model to it to validate, or I can just instantiate the validation object within the user model or even write the validation code into the user model, however, I'm thinking that this would be wasteful as the validation object/code is only used when registering, and editing user data.  Therefore, I'm leaning to keeping the user validation object external.  Can someone advise me as to what the best practices are?  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, I'd say make the User model responsible for maintaining its own validity. Put these invariants in the model itself. Then, *nothing* can put a User in an invalid state, not just your current creation and editing features.

Comment: Appreciate the input, Thom.  As a follow up question, if I had to do something like check the database to ensure that the username is not taken, assuming i'm using a data mapper, where would I put this code to perform validation which requires talking to the database layer?

Comment: That's a bit less clear-cut: you could have a User that was valid *in itself*, but not valid in the context of the database. Because your data mapper probably abstracts away the database entirely as a program entity, I'd center this validation in the model. You could check for this contextual validation when you try to "commit" the User. You could also try to verity the uniqueness constraint every time you mutated the username, but this would not guarantee that the username was unique when it was later inserted.

Comment: If the username is (as I suspect) permanently immutable, then simply checking and objecting on User creation would be both sufficient and simple.

Answer (score 2):

I've usually kept my validation code separate from my model code in an MVC application. Essentially all my models assume that data passed into them is already clean/correct. This allows for more readable model code, and more centralization/reuse of validation code.

Comment: Thx for your input, Nicolas.  What about encapsulating the validation code into an object and instantiating it within the model?  Wouldn't this allow for reuse of validation code and keep the model code readable?  Also, as I asked Thom above, where do you put code which has to perform validation which needs to talk with the database layer, i.e. checking that a username is unique?  Your help/time is much appreciated!

Comment: You could do this too (encapsulating validation in an object called from the model code) of course. I think actually that would have the "bulletproof external interface" that Thom Smith mentions above, which is nice. In terms of validation code interacting with a database, there's no reason you can't put that in a validation module... Validation can be seen to be a multi-stage affair: e.g. 1) does the data contain bad chars? 2) if not, is it a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to keep the validation code separate from the model. In fact, it is more related to the code of the interface.

When you create the model you cannot be sure for the interface. Maybe you will have 2 or more forms that manipulate data of a single object:

```
                                    ---------
                                    | Form1 |
---------       -------------   /   ---------
| model |   -   | Validator |
---------       -------------   \   ---------
                                    | Form2 |
                                    ---------
```

If the validator is bound to the model, you cannot support multiple forms. Suppose that you had one validator for both forms. Then you could end up with some really funny messages. For example, "The field X is mandatory" and have the user wonder where on earth field X is. (Field X is in the other form...)

So, this solution is better, from this point of view:

```
                --------------     ---------
                | Validator1 |  -  | Form1 |
---------  /    --------------     ---------
| model |  
---------  \    --------------     ---------
                | Validator2 |  -  | Form2 |
                --------------     ---------
```

Comment: You could solve this problem by separating validation and error reporting. If we're talking about a form representing a model object, then your model would report that one (or more) of the attempted mutations was invalid and the form logic would receive that error and determine, based on its knowledge of its own fields and the context of the interaction, that the culprit was an empty field. Any form constraints not directly resulting from model constraints would be represented only in the form. The form-side validations corresponding to model validations can be generated automatically.

Comment: @Thom Smith: So, what you actually suggest is adding a central validator next to the model and before the two form validators, right?

Comment: Basically, as in your first model. This validator would only check and report whether the given data is valid given the model's constraints. Then, each form would need to interpret this report and present it to the user in the context of the form. The model validation wouldn't produce error message strings, or know about form fields.